# How can I make my slider loop continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used this jquery code to make my testimonials section work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var testimonialItem = $(".testimonial-wrapper .testimonial-item");
  var lengthOfItem = testimonialItem.length;
  var counter = 0;  
  testimonialItem.hide();
  setTimeout(function(){
    startIteration(counter);
  }, 1000);
  function startIteration(counter) {
    testimonialItem.eq(counter).fadeIn('slow', function() {
      if(counter<=lengthOfItem){ 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        testimonialItem.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        if (counter == lengthOfItem) {
            counter = 0;  
        }
        else{
            counter++;
        }
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            startIteration(counter);
        }, 500);    
        });
        }, 2000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Seeing through my [pen](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/OmXZWJ), I realised that minutes later after leaving the link, when I go back, the slider disappears.
Is there a way I can fix that so that the slider loops all the time?

Also, how can I add the navigation bullets so that each time a testimonials changes, a bullet also changes color as you can see in the example image?

[image]

[Here my codepen](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/OmXZWJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I can't tell that I've solved anything. I think you may be running into some other issues with long-standing timers, but my googling isn't coming up with anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var testimonialItem = $(".testimonial-wrapper .testimonial-item");
  var lengthOfItem = testimonialItem.length;
  testimonialItem.hide();

  setTimeout(startIteration.bind(0), 1000);

  function startIteration(counter) {
    var item = testimonialItem.eq(counter)
    item.fadeIn('slow', function() {
      setTimeout(function() { 
        item.fadeOut('slow', function() {
          startIteration((counter + 1) %  lengthOfItem);  
        });
      }, 2000);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.queue()`, `.delay()`, `.promise()`, `.then()`, repeated scheduling to call same function when queue array does not contain any further functions to call

```js
var items = $(".testimonial-item").hide();

function testimonials() {
  return $({}).queue("testimonials", $.map(items, function(el) {
      return function(next) {
        $(el).fadeIn("slow", function() {
          $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", next)
        })
      }
    })).dequeue("testimonials").promise("testimonials")
    .then(testimonials)
}

testimonials()
```

```css
hr {
  height: 4px;
  border: none;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #7BC83A;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.testimonial-item {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.872447;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 testimonial-wrapper">
  <div class="testimonial-item">
    <h3>Testimonials</h3>
    <hr>
    <h4>Shaf/ Seo</h4>
    <blockquote>
      <p>Hi</p>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-item" style="opacity: 1;">
    <h3>Testimonials</h3>
    <hr>
    <h4>Shaje/ As</h4>
    <blockquote>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text Lorem Ipsum Simply Dummy text</p>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can substitute `.then(function() {
      setTimeout(testimonials, 500)
    })` for `.then(testimonials)` if you want to delay next call to `testimonials` for `500` milliseconds

Comment: so far it seems like it works.
Is there a way I can the bullets navigation from your code? know its not the main question but would appreciate if you can support on that too.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico _"Is there a way I can the bullets navigation from your code?"_ Not sure what you mean. What are "the bullets"?

Comment: just edited my question so you can see the image exampled

Comment: @WosleyAlarico That is an entirely separate Question, no? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I completely understand and for that reason I had mentioned that I know it was not the main question. Appreciate the support anyway.