# Is there a clean way to infinitely use async functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

According to ESLint some code like this is not 'clean code'

```
for(;;) {
  await *async function*
}
```

My aim is to infinitely loop a certain function, executing it one by one, without eventually crashing my app because of call stack limits. I have thought about it for some time but couldn't come up with anything else that would do the same. What ESLint suggests also wouldn't work in my case; they suggest starting all of the functions in the loop and awaiting their resolve/reject callback outside of the loop by using .all().

Help would be appreciated! I just want to write this as cleanly as possible

Comment: how about `while(true)`?

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager ESLint doesn't like await in any loop https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop

It might just be the only solution for what I want to do, so then it wouldn't be a problem, but otherwise id of course like the cleanest solution :P

Comment: Why is what ESLint logs important?

Comment: Ok! How about `setInterval`?

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager that wouldn't wait for the function to be completed, it would be a guess at best :P But, like estus said Ill just remove the rule. I started using eslint today and really like it so I guess it kinda made me go crazy x)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the ESLint documentation says:

> In many cases the iterations of a loop are not actually independent of
>   each-other. For example, the output of one iteration might be used as
>   the input to another. Or, loops may be used to retry asynchronous
>   operations that were unsuccessful. In such cases it makes sense to use
>   await within a loop and it is recommended to disable the rule via a
>   standard ESLint disable comment.

So if it makes sense for you to wait in every iteration, disable this rule. If you can parallelize the async calls use `Promise.all`.

To disable an ESLint rule only at some place in the code do it like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
//Your code here...
/* eslint-enable no-await-in-loop */
```

Comment: Ill disable it, thanks. I went a little crazy on following eslint rules :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are several patterns which could be used to "infinitely loop". You can schedule the same function to be called when the function completes.

Comment: This would eventually crash my app because of the call stack ;(

Comment: No, it should not "crash" the app.

Comment: Create a function that calls itself, run your code and wait for a bit. Eventually youll get that call stack error

Comment: That is not accurate. See [multiple, sequential fetch() Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034574/multiple-sequential-fetch-promise/). You can also use an async iterator to perform the same task, see the code at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349837) at [Run multiple recursive Promises and break when requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349721/run-multiple-recursive-promises-and-break-when-requested)

Comment: @timgfx Have already tried the code several times over. If your concern is what ESLint logs do not use ESLint

Comment: function justTryItAndYoullSee() {
 justTryItAndYoullSee();
    }
    justTryItAndYoullSee();

Comment: @timgfx you should read about [tail calls](http://benignbemine.github.io/2015/07/19/es6-tail-calls/)

Comment: [How can I make my slider loop continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595870/how-can-i-make-my-slider-loop-continuously/), [Does it consider recursion if I call onload event on the funcion which I'm inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329784/does-it-consider-recursion-if-i-call-onload-event-on-the-funcion-which-im-insid)

Comment: @Sidney since my example has to be infinite that wont work since itll still exceed the call stack at some point

Comment: @gues271314 those examples are all not infinite though

Comment: @timgfx How is the code at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48370317/is-there-a-clean-way-to-infinitely-use-async-functions/48370382#comment83727606_48370382 related to the question?

Comment: _"those examples are all not infinite though"_ ? Yes they are, including the code at the second comment

Comment: @guest271314 ah I assumed that they werent infinite because they work. they work for some time because of callbacks. the code I posted is an iterating function without callbacks, which will instantly exceed the call stack limim and crash

Comment: @timgfx No, it will not when coded properly. That is, as suggested by Chris Riebschlager using `while(true)`

Comment: @guest271314 while(true) isnt an iterating function. the reason i want to use a loop instead of an iterating function is that iterating functions crash after some time

Comment: @timgfx It is not clear what the issue is. If you are iterating using a `for` or `for..of` loop how is "infinitely" related to the inquiry?